# Open-circuit alternator

Tags: power, thermal, alternator

Is it dangerous to run a permanent magnet alternator open-circuited? No current can flow so is all the power dissipated as heat? Is there even power generated in the inductive coils?

Answer (score 1):

Since power is current multiplied by voltage, and no current is flowing, it is not power dissipation you need to worry about.

Voltage will be generated, but it shouldn't cause a problem.

Comment: Hi @evildemonic, thanks for responding. What is your source for this? Did you read it in a textbook or experience it from working with PM alternators, or are you just referencing basic circuits theory?

Comment: This is from basic electronics theory and general experience with motors and alternators of all types.  A voltage will be produced, but actual power will not be generated.

Comment: I heard from someone else, who also has some experience with motors and alternators, that after enough time running open-circuit it will overheat. So I don't think I can come to a conclusion one way or another before testing it myself.